# How to handle situation if message will not come in queue after timeout. Is it possible with Message Broker?

Tags: timeout, queue, message, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I think I described almost everything I need in title. So there is some WMB flows. And one wait for the answer in queue. I need to throw exception if there will be no message in queue after timeout.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possibe, but you will need to develop it in your flows. MQ is made for asyncronous communication, so a timeout is not something which is native to it. I can think of 2 possible solutions now:

- Use the TimeoutControl and TimeoutNotification nodes in your flows

In the flow which sends the request, after sending the request you add a TimeoutControl node and set up the desired timeout.
Create a new flow, which starts with the TimeoutNotification flow. In that flow you send your timeout error if the response has not yet been received.
And to know which response has been received you can use different methods, for example the flows sending the request and receiving the response could maintain a database table, or you could store this information in a queue as well.

- Start waiting for the response after sending the request

Set up the response handler flow to start with an MQ Input followed by an MQ Get node. You listen for the response with the MQ Get, on which you can set a wait interval, that will be your timeout threshold. The MQ Input gets technical messages sent by the request sender flow after sending the request.
This is a worse solution then the first, as you will block a message flow thread while listening for the response.

Or you can just make 1 flow to send the request and receive the response, receiving the response with an MQ Get node.
This is even worse as you will need to turn off transactionality for the MQ Output sending the request.

Comment: Attila, please clarify one thing. If we use first scenario we will have 3 flows. One with request, one with TimeoutNotification and one with response handling, right? Example: the request is done well, response received, but the timer will continue running and fire message to TimeoutNotification. Then error will send anyway if I understand correct. How to avoid it?

Comment: Correct, you will have 3 flows. In your request flow you need to store which message ids you are waiting a response for. And you remove the id when you get the response. So your timeout flow only sends the error, when you get a timeout with a MsgId, which is in the list. The TimeoutControl node can store data, which will be sent to the TimeoutNotification node, in that data you can store the MsgId of the message you start the timeout for. And the list of MsgIds you are waiting a response for can be stored whatever way is the most suitable, in a DB, in a Q, or in shared variables for example.